# Strange linker error in C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm trying to use the code from this project from CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/587629/A-Delaunay-triangulation-function-in-C

The problem is that the function which should be used in my project is:

```
WORD* BuildTriangleIndexList (void *pointList, float factor, int numberOfInputPoints, int numDimensions, int clockwise, int *numTriangleVertices)
```

which has a body inside the `.cpp` file, but no declaration in the header, so using the code as-is, I obviously get a compilation error complaining that it can't find the function.

So, I've tried to add the declaration to the header, and it compiles correctly, but the linker gave me:

```
Errore  1   error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "unsigned short * __cdecl BuildTriangleIndexList(void *,float,int,int,int,int *)" (?BuildTriangleIndexList@@YAPAGPAXMHHHPAH@Z) non risolto nella funzione "protected: virtual void __thiscall TutorialApplication::createScene(void)" (?createScene@TutorialApplication@@MAEXXZ)  C:\Progetti\TestShader\TestShader\TutorialApplication.obj   TestShader
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually *defined* (i.e. implemented) the function in a source file that is compiled and linked in your project?

Comment: As Joachim pointed, you should add an header file and add the prototype of this function. Then, in your .cpp you include the header and the issue should be risolved.

Comment: As stated in the original post, I've added the prototype to the header, otherwise I can't even get it to compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definition is missing, either you link with a library that has the definition of the function or define on your own, no other alternative.
Suspect that the call is in C, so, wrap the definition as:
extern "C" {
// delclaration as well as definition both 
}
Another possibility is that is it is C++ member function of a class, make sure all overridden member functions have an implementation (function body), if not put as pure virtual (abstract)

Comment: No, the cpp file, wich contains the actual implementation is compiled in the same vs2013 project.

Comment: edited my answer, may be wrapping with extern "C" is required in that case

Comment: Thank you! the solution was to wrap the function as extern "C"!